# How do I put special characters in a tag?

Tags: support, tags, special-characters

For instance, I want an ampersand in D&D, but it gets filtered out.

Comment: URL encode it, if you have to.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You can spell out "and" instead. Like `[ponies-and-unicorns]`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

From the Ask Question page, the only allowed characters for tags are: a-z, 0-9, +, #, -, .

However, I do have a solution:

- Create the tag using the name spelled out in full, using hyphens to separate the words.
- Create a tag synonym mapping `[dd]` to the full name tag.

The latter will ensure that anyone who *tried* to type 'd&d' in the box will have the proper tag put on the question. This works because the ampersand is silently stripped from the input, resulting in an actual input of `[dd]`. Hopefully using `[dd]` for this doesn't collide with another tag you actually need.

Comment: [Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Answer (score 2):

How about [dnd] instead?

Comment: Do not disturb?

Comment: Drag​-​n​-​drop?